# Google Analytics Opt-out

Tags: google-analytics

To be OK with the nonsense cookie law of the Grosse European Komission, I've built this little script to opt-out the GA tracking code. The result is a popup asking once in the session for OK vs CANCEL GA. What do you think of it?

```
(function() {
  var message = "GOOGLE ANALYTICS COOKIE\nCookie or not cookie, that is the question\n\nI opt for Google Analytics pageview anonymous tracking.\n\nJe consens au suivi d'audience anonyme Google Analytics.";
  if (!sessionStorage['key_name']) {
    if (confirm(message) == true) {
     sessionStorage.setItem('key_name', 'gaOK');
    }
    else {
     sessionStorage.setItem('key_name', 'gaOut');
    }
  }
  if (sessionStorage['key_name'] == 'gaOK') {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-N', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }
})();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should probably go to the code review SO site.

Comment: What is the code review SO site? I don't think this question is off-topic, because I'm living in France and this topic is important for us Europeans. If my GA opt-out code can help someone it would be a good thing and I only wanted to ask for advice as to my code legality and functionality.

Comment: @PascalMyrta It's Off-Topic (On Stack Overflow) because Stack Overflow is about **specific** programming problems. "Why do I get a Stack Overflow in this Loop", "Why does my program crash on line 20", "How can I improve the memory-efficiency of this algorithm?". [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), on the other hand, is exactly the site for this kind of question. "My code works, is it any good?" is the basis of every CR question.

Comment: There are other such questions on Sack Overflow, ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941201/toggle-google-analytics-opt-out-opt-in